# FMDB SQL query not returning any data

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

I am making a request to my FMDB that looks like this

```
long long lstartDate = 1467331200000;
long long lendDate = 1468108800000;


    [_queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *database) {
        FMResultSet * result = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM dayEPOCTable WHERE date >= '?' AND date <= '?' ", lstartDate, lendDate];
```

However when the query has finished I do not have any items available in the result.

The lendDate & lstartDate both have hard coded values that exists in the table, I have gone to Devices, downloaded the container to check to make sure those values appear on the SQL db.

What I am trying to do is return all rows between and including the lstartDate and lendDate that are in the table.

**UPDATE**:
Casting long long to NSNumber worked. updated code is as follows

```
NSNumber *lstartDate = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:1467331200000];
     NSNumber *lendDate = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:1468108800000];

[_queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *database) {
            FMResultSet * result = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM dayEPOCTable WHERE date >= '?' AND date <= '?' ", lstartDate, lendDate];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `result == nil`? If so, that means that there was an error and you can look at `[database lastErrorMessage]` to see what the error was.

One error jumps out at me, though: When you use `?` placeholders in your SQL, you should not use quotation marks. So remove those:

```
FMResultSet * result = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM dayEPOCTable WHERE date >= ? AND date <= ?", @(lstartDate), @(lendDate)];
NSAssert(result, @"executeQuery error: %@", [database lastErrorMessage]);
```

There certainly can be lots of other possible sources of problems, but this is where I'd start, namely eliminating the quotation marks and checking to see if `executeQuery` succeeded or not, and if it failed retrieve the SQLite error message.

---

Note, as the [`executeQuery` documentation says](http://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMDatabase.html#//api/name/executeQuery:) with regard to the variadic parameters supplied for the `?` placeholders:

> Optional parameters to bind to `?` placeholders in the SQL statement. These should be Objective-C objects (e.g. `NSString`, `NSNumber`, etc.), not fundamental C data types (e.g. `int`, `char *`, etc.).

So in the above example, I've replaced `lstartDate` and `lendDate` with `@(lstartDate)` and `@(lendDate)`. This makes them `NSNumber` objects.

Comment: I have tried the following and the query crashes before I can log the error, It takes me to FMDB line 817:obj = va_arg(args, id);

This issue goes away when i use '?' so I am not sure what to do here.

Comment: Also if it helps date is stored as a BIGINT int the table

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that those were `long long`. You should wrap those in a `NSNumber` (e.g. using the `@(...)` syntax for `NSNumber`, if you want, like in my revised answer). This variadic version expects all of the parameters to be objects, but `long long` is a fundamental data type.

Comment: oh right.. that worked! but was very painful as no meaning full errors were given. thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah, I really dislike the variadic parameters those FMDB methods use, as the compiler can't reasonably warn you about using non-object parameters. C'est la vie.